# Suppose that $(S_n, \circ)$ is a symmetric group with $n \geq 3$, then a permutation of $(i,j)=(1,i)(1,j)(1,i)$

Tags: symmetric-groups

So I started studying the symmetric group, and was given this statement:

> Suppose that $(S_n, \circ)$ is a symmetric group with $n \geq 3$, then a permutation of $(i,j)=(1,i)(1,j)(1,i)$

And I fail to understand why is that the case. Even by drawing an example, I fail to see why that is the case. Could someone clarify this, please?

Comment: to be thourough you should stipulate that $1,i,j$ are different else the formula doesn't always work. It works if $i=1$ and $i\ne j$ for instance but not if $j=1$ and $i\neq j$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Omiting all the fixed points in the second (bracket-) representation we get

$(1,i) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & i & j \\ i & 1 & j \end{bmatrix}$

therefore

$(1,j) \circ (1,i) =  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & i & j \\ i & j & 1 \end{bmatrix} = (1,i,j)$

and so we conclude

$(1,i) \circ (1,j) \circ (1,i)  = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & i & j \\ 1 & j & i \end{bmatrix} = (i,j)$.

Does that make it clearer now?

---

EDIT: If you're not familiar with the bracket notation: It just shows which value on the top row gets mapped to which value on the bottom row. Furthermore I use the convention that if $f=(a,b,c)$ then $f(a) = b$, $f(b) = c$  and lastly if $a,b,c$ are premutations I interpret $abc = a \circ b \circ c$ so $(abc)(x) = a(b(c(x)))$.

Comment: Yes, thank you a lot! It's a lot clearer now!

Answer (score 0):

The only elements which are moved are $1,i,j$. Let's  what happens to each in detail:

- $1\mapsto i=i\mapsto 1$;
- $i\mapsto 1=1\mapsto j =j$;
- $j=j\mapsto1\mapsto i$.